# Selenoid - WebdriverException: disconected, not connected to DevTools

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, microsoft-edge, selenoid

I am running my tests in selenoid - edge.
On my local machine everything is working fine. But once I am running it through the pipeline, all of the tests are failing. Can you help?

```
Smoke001_Login and verify username                                    org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.opentelemetry.OpenTelemetryTracer INFO Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
2024-01-05T11:06:16.8777711Z org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake INFO Detected dialect: W3C
2024-01-05T11:06:16.8778727Z Loader stayed for (sec): 1
2024-01-05T11:06:16.8781910Z Loader stayed for (sec): 2
2024-01-05T11:06:17.7956148Z | FAIL |
2024-01-05T11:06:17.7965496Z Teardown failed:
2024-01-05T11:06:17.7966567Z WebDriverException: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
2024-01-05T11:06:17.7967684Z   (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
2024-01-05T11:06:17.7971016Z   (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=120.0.2210.91)
2024-01-05T11:06:17.7973102Z Build info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'
2024-01-05T11:06:17.7976574Z Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
2024-01-05T11:06:17.7977635Z Command: [0ad677769f66101860de1e68815310d2, close {}]
2024-01-05T11:06:17.7981992Z Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: MicrosoftEdge, browserVersion: 120.0.2210.91, fedcm:accounts: true, javascriptEnabled: true, ms:edgeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:54901}, msedge: {msedgedriverVersion: 120.0.2210.91  networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
```

I have checked if we have on our virtual machine everything the same as I have in my local machine and it seems to be fine

Comment: Make sure you are using Selenoid version 1.11.0 and above. https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/releases/tag/1.11.0